# Mapbox iOS StyleURL toggling causing crash

Tags: ios, mapbox

I have an issue with toggling style URL (custom vs satellite) while also having several tileset URL's being loaded. Our app runs very smoothly across the board, but gets increasingly bogged down the more you toggle the StyleURL (we have a custom roads map from MapBox studio and toggle to satellite). Our app "crashes" if you toggle between the two enough times, typically between 10-20 times without a time limit. So our users do run into this fairly often. Some details below.

Based on the "human-code" below, we're thinking it has something to do with the fact that we are reloading all our layers (and sources) in `ViewDidFinishLoading` which occurs on every layer toggle event?

> Mapbox 4.7-4.9
>
> iOS11.0+
>
> Seems to happen across HW platforms Seems to
>   not depend on connectivity, Wifi/Cell/etc

The code. I can eventually come up with some example code with links to some tileset data, but in the short-term it's really simple. Below is some human code in case the problem is basic to a mapbox expert

```
ViewDidload(){
// Setup basic mapbox parameters, callout styleURL, load mapbox view. No problems here.
}

ViewDIDFinishLoading(){
// load all of our custom tilesets using urls. We have MGLMultipolygons, MGLmultipolylines, points, etc. 
// We noticed this is called whenever you toggle StyleURLs, and so we HAVE ALSO FOUND THAT WE NEED TO RELOAD BOTH THE SOURCES AND LAYERS INTO THE STYLE OBJECT IN THIS FUNCTION on every button press where we want to change from different style URLs
}

On BtnClickedToggleSatellite_Roads() //Switches the map between StyleURLS
styleURL != lastStyleURL
//Note that this calls the ViewDidFinishloading where we reload all our sources and layers
}
```

Comment: Could you share the crash message or a stack trace? Also, do you see the crash if you add the tileset in [-mapView:didFinishLoadingStyle:
](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/4.9.0/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:didFinishLoadingStyle:)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! We will try moving this code from didFinishLoading() to didFinishLoadingStyle, haven't tried that yet. Below is some info on a crash we just reproduced. Not sure how to best capture stack trace?

Comment: Working on attaching debug output and stack trace, hang tight [eye roll]

Comment: @jmkiley not sure the best way to share the debug output and stack trace, so I created a .pdf via Google Drive. The stack trace is just a screen shot of the stack trace that crashed (com.mapbox.mbgl.Worker) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vet8bHtJv0chJfoSjB0TYXtRAFeqq_Mr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Correction: I am actually using the didFinishLoading style delegate. See actual code below. <br/> func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
       print("didFinishLoading()")

        mapStateLayers.load_all_states(mapView)
        mapStateLayers.format_all_states(mapView, currentStreamGID)
        mapStateLayers.loadHighlighter(mapView, currentStreamGID, layerMode)
        
    }

Comment: Update: I went back to the MapBox iOS example here: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/switch-styles/. I added ALL of the functionality and code from our other project in the "mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle)" function. App runs fine with pretty clearly no issues when toggling very rapidly between satellite and roads. So there must be some non-core difference between the example project and our companies project thats adding to this. Will further investigate tomorrow.